# blinking led continuously with 1 second in C language(atmega328p)

Tags: c, atmega

I am using AVR Studio5 to program the arduino uno rev3 with atmel atmega328p.Now , I am trying blink a led continuously within 1 second . 
The code is :

```
    PORTD = 0b10001010;
    TCNT1H = 0xBB;
    TCNT1L = 0xBB;
    TCCR1A = 0;
    TCCR1B = 5; // prescaler is 1024
    while((TIFR1 & (1<<TOV1)) == 0)
    {
        temp = TCNT1H; 
        while ((TCNT1H - temp) >= 11);
        PORTD  ^= 1<<7; // blinking as expected
    }
    TIFR1 = 1<<TOV1;
    TCCR1A = 0;
    TCCR1B = 0;
```

The above code shows that I use a timer1 lasting for 1 second in which I attempt to blink the PORTD.7 led for each 0.032768s.
But , now , the problem is that the timer works for delaying 1 second but the led keep lighting without blinking . Please help .
( P.S the circuit works fine )

Complement :
If I use the following code , it shows the led blinking.

```
for ( a = 0;a<2;a++)
{
  PORTD = 0b00001010;
    TCNT1H = 0xEE;
    TCNT1L = 0xEE;
    TCCR1A = 0;
    TCCR1B = 5; // prescaler is 1024
    while((TIFR1 & (1<<TOV1)) == 0);
    TIFR1 = 1<<TOV1;
    TCCR1A = 0;
    TCCR1B = 0;

    PORTD = 0b10001010;
    TCNT1H = 0xEE;
    TCNT1L = 0xEE;
    TCCR1A = 0;
    TCCR1B = 5; // prescaler is 1024
    while((TIFR1 & (1<<TOV1)) == 0);
    TIFR1 = 1<<TOV1;
    TCCR1A = 0;
    TCCR1B = 0;
}
```

But , for the simplicity , I prefer the most top method if working .

Comment: Can you use usleep function? Some more info: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/usleep.html

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond I'd guess he does not have an os.

Comment: If OP is using `avr-gcc` a simple delay can be used with `_delay_ms` function from `util/delay.h`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion . However , I just want to use timer1 to blink the led.

Comment: Have you configured the pin as output using the ddrd register?

Comment: Yes , all the pin configurations are correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
    while ((TCNT1H - temp) >= 10)
    {
        PORTD  ^= 1<<7; // blinking as expected
    }
```

You are blinking too fast, so fast that actually what are you are seeing is a LED with half the luminosity. You need to add some delay between two invocations of `PORTD ^= 1<<7`.

Comment: I rewrite "while ((TCNT1H - temp) >= 10)
    {
        PORTD  ^= 1<<7; // blinking as expected
    }" to "while ((TCNT1H - temp) >= 30);
   PORTD  ^= 1<<7;" to make a larger time interval but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that should be done with an interrupt.

```
void TMR_init(void)
{
    DDRD|=_BV(PD7); //bit 7 of port D to output
    TCNT1=0; //reset the timer counter
    OCR1AL=0xC6; //depends on your osc. This values are for 12MHz
    OCR1AH=0x2D; //with 12 000 000Hz / 1024 it takes 11718 ticks for 1 sec->0x2D C6
    TIMSK1|=_BV(OCIE1A); //enable interrupt on output compare A (when timer value == value in the OCR1AL/H-registers)
    TCCR1A=0; //normal operation
    TCCR1B=_BV(CS12) | _BV(CS10); //prescaler 1024 and starts the timer

    sei(); //enable interrupts
}

//isr
SIGNAL(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{
    PORTD^=_BV(PD7); //toggle    
}
```

This code should work but is untested. Don't forget to include avr/interrupt.h. Some macros may differ due to version differences of the compiler.